"How can I address the lack of correlation and a low R-squared value in my univariate linear regression when the data is scattered?"
**
"I'm trying to find a correlation between the confirmed cases and deaths rates against HUMIDEX values. As you can see, the data is very scattered, so I understand that polynomial and logarithmic normalization are applied when the data follows a trend. I'm not sure if there's a way to normalize the data to find any correlation. The issue is that the data is highly scattered, causing conflict. Or is it simply that there's no correlation?"
Attached are the graphs


Welcome to SO.  Transformations of the data are used to better fit the assumptions of things like linear regression, like normality of the residuals.  They dont tend to make patterns appear where there are none, though there are always exceptions.  These data , im sorry to say, look to have no correlation in them.  Good luck with your work- data analysis is always challenging.

"Highly scattered" is almost a synonym of "no correlation" -- not quite, because there can be other patterns. But no such other pattern is apparent in your data.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
